# EDMX model is generating Defining Query node even the table has a primary key

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ado.net, linq-to-entities

I am using a custom ado.net provider for a java based SQL database. I'm now integrating Entity Framework using this custom ado.net provider. It is generating model from existing tables. But somehow during model generation, it is creating "DefiningQuery" node for the table and giving this following error. I have provided the whole SSDL content below. As you can see after the error message, the table definition is provided with Entity Key, which is the PRIMARY KEY in the database.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <edmx:Edmx Version="2.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/10/edmx">
    <!-- EF Runtime content -->
  <edmx:Runtime>
   <!-- SSDL content -->
   <edmx:StorageModels>
   <Schema Namespace="Model21.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="myADO.NET.Provider" ProviderManifestToken="myADO" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl">
    <EntityContainer Name="Model21StoreContainer">
      <EntitySet Name="TEST3" EntityType="Model21.Store.TEST3" store:Type="Tables" store:Schema="DBO" store:Name="TEST3">
        <DefiningQuery>SELECT 
  "TEST3"."ID" AS "ID", 
  "TEST3"."NAME" AS "NAME"
  FROM "DBO"."TEST3" AS "TEST3"</DefiningQuery>
      </EntitySet>
    </EntityContainer>
    <!--Errors Found During Generation:
  warning 6002: The table/view 'myDatabase.DBO.TEST3' does not have a primary key defined. The key has been inferred and the definition was created as a read-only table/view.
  -->
    <EntityType Name="TEST3">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="ID" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="ID" Type="integer" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
      <Property Name="NAME" Type="varchar" MaxLength="50" />
       </EntityType>
      </Schema>
   </edmx:StorageModels>
```

Any help and pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The underlying data structures and their relationships would be helpful.

Comment: Do you mean in the database?

Comment: Yes please! Without knowing what it's trying to generate from, working out a problem with what it's generated is not really possible.

Comment: Although the error message does give you a clue about something that might need doing.

Comment: There is just one table in the "DBO" schema:                            COLUMN_NAME         |TYPE_NAME|DECIMAL_DIGITS|NUM_PREC_RADIX|COLUMN_SIZE|COLUMN_DEF          |CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH|IS_NULLABLE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID                  |INTEGER  |0             |10            |10         |GENERATED_BY_DEFAULT|NULL             |NO         
NAME                |VARCHAR  |NULL          |NULL          |50         |NULL                |100              |YES

Comment: Is the column in the database nullable? It is hard to read it from your comment but IS_NULLABLE and YES are the rightmost column values...

Comment: Was this ever resolved? Having same issue. Ef designer randomly started creating a defining query for a table that has a primary key.